# Email Config Google Cloud Platform

Tags: cpanel, google-cloud-platform, email

Best regards

I have an instance configured in Google Cloud, where I installed cPanel to manage more easily my web project. Everything runs fine, but as much a problem to use email accounts.

I set all MX records in the Network section of the console Google, and have also done the same in cPanel. Then I created email accounts in cPanel, and I can access the accounts (I use RoundCube as an email client), but when sending an email, this is going, but does not arrive to destination, or conversely, sent from another account (such as a Gmail) email, and this is sent but not up to my new personal email account.

I realized that what happens is that Google does not allow use ports 25 and 587, so must perform other configuration.

Someone could help me to know how I can create and use email accounts, from a "normal" way, without using Google Apps (because it is paid) or services like Mailgun.

Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use any third party email service for mail. Please check following URL,

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ports 25 and 587 since GCP block all outbound traffic from those ports, I suggest you use  port 2525 since that's the only smtp port that GCP does not block and most major vendors use.